# How can you validate the presence of a belongs to association with Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Say I have a basic Rails app with a basic one-to-many relationship where each comment belongs to an article:

```
$ rails blog
$ cd blog
$ script/generate model article name:string
$ script/generate model comment article:belongs_to body:text
```

Now I add in the code to create the associations, but I also want to be sure that when I create a comment, it always has an article:

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments
end

class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :article
  validates_presence_of :article_id
end
```

So now let's say I'd like to create an article with a comment all at once:

```
$ rake db:migrate
$ script/console
```

If you do this:

```
>> article = Article.new
=> #<Article id: nil, name: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
>> article.comments.build
=> #<Comment id: nil, article_id: nil, body: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
>> article.save!
```

You'll get this error:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Comments is invalid
```

Which makes sense, because the comment has no page_id yet.

```
>> article.comments.first.errors.on(:article_id)
=> "can't be blank"
```

So if I remove the `validates_presence_of :article_id` from `comment.rb`, then I could do the save, but that would also allow you to create comments without an article id.  What's the typical way of handling this?

**UPDATE**: Based on Nicholas' suggestion, here's a implementation of save_with_comments that works but is ugly:

```
def save_with_comments
  save_with_comments!
rescue
  false
end

def save_with_comments!
  transaction do
    comments = self.comments.dup
    self.comments = []
    save!
    comments.each do |c|
      c.article = self
      c.save!
    end
  end
  true
end
```

Not sure I want add something like this for every one-to-many association.  Andy is probably correct in that is just best to avoid trying to do a cascading save and use the nested attributes solution.  I'll leave this open for a while to see if anyone has any other suggestions.

Answer (score 23):

I've also been investigating this topic and here is my summary:

The root cause why this doesn't work OOTB (at least when using `validates_presence_of :article` and not `validates_presence_of :article_id`) is the fact that rails doesn't use an identity map internally and therefore will not by itself know that `article.comments[x].article == article`

I have found three workarounds to make it work with a little effort:

1. Save the article before creating the comments (rails will automatically pass the article id that was generated during the save to each newly created comments; see Nicholas Hubbard's response)
2. Explicitly set the article on the comment after creating it (see W. Andrew Loe III's response)
3. Use inverse_of:

   ```
   class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
     has_many :comments, :inverse_of => :article
   end
   ```

This last solution was bot yet mentioned in this article but seems to be rails' quick fix solution for the lack of an identity map. It also looks the least intrusive one of the three to me.

Comment: Inverse_of answers the question perfectly. Unlike the other solutions, it will play nicely with other Rails idioms like accepts_nested_attributes_for.

Comment: This worked perfectly for me, using a deeply nested form with nested attributes. By saving the parent model first the creation of child objects with validation on the parent_id means I can keep validation :)

Comment: Setting inverse_of also worked for me but I had to change the presence validation from the <association>_id, to just <association> to get it to work.

Comment: Yes.. This is the answer `:inverse_of` when presence of an association is required even if it is not saved yet

Answer (score 2):

Instead of validating the presence of the article's id you could validate the presence of the article.

```
validates_presence_of :article
```

Then when you are creating your comment:

```
article.comments.build :article => article
```

Comment: Is there a difference b/w validates_presence_of :article and validates_presence_of :article_id ? Both always seemed okay to me (Rails 3).

Comment: An article that hasn't been saved may still be present, but lacking an id until the entire save transaction completes.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct. The article needs an id before this validation will work. One way around this is the save the article, like so:

```
>> article = Article.new
=> #<Article id: nil, name: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
>> article.save!
=> true
>> article.comments.build
=> #<Comment id: nil, article_id: 2, body: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
>> article.save!
=> true
```

If you are creating a new article with a comment in one method or action then I would recommend creating the article and saving it, then creating the comment, but wrapping the entire thing inside of a Article.transaction block so that you don't end up with any extra articles.

Comment: Since I can only comment on my own answer. Daniel is correct you could use validates presence of article instead of article_id, but if you are using the article.comments.build this will still not work due to the builder that rails uses.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this problem adding this follow line to my _comment.html.erb:

"NEW" if form.object.new_record? %>

Now, the validation works in stand alone form, and in multi form too.

Answer (score 1):

This fails because there is no identity map in Rails 2.3 or 3.0. You can manually fix it by stitching them together.

```
a = Article.new
c = a.comments.build
c.article = a
a.save!
```

This is horrible, and what the identity map in 3.1 will help to fix (in addition to performance gains). `c.article` and `a.comments.first.article` are different objects without an identity map.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Rails 2.3 you are using the new nested model stuff. I have noticed the same failures with `validates_presence_of` as you pointed out, or if `:null => false` was specified in the migration for that field.

If your intent is to create nested models, you should add `accepts_nested_attributes_for :comments` to `article.rb`. This would allow you to:

```
a = Article.new
a.comments_attributes = [{:body => "test"}]
a.save!  # creates a new Article and a new Comment with a body of "test"
```

What you have is the way it should work to me, but I'm seeing that it doesn't with Rails 2.3.2. I debugged a `before_create` in comment using your code and no `article_id` is supplied through the build (it is nil) so this is not going to work. You'd need to save the Article first as Nicholas pointed out, or remove validation.

Comment: Yeah, I think the problem is that there is no article id yet, because the article has been saved, because this runs during validate.  I believe the order of operations is:

1. valid the article
2. validate all the comments
3. save the article 
4. save the comments

So step 2 fails, because there is no id yet.