# Rails: Validating association after save?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

I have a `User` model which has many `roles`. Roles contains a `user_id` field, which I want to `validate_presence_of`

The issue is: if I assign a role to user upon create, the validation fails because no user_id is set. Now, I *do* want to validate that a user_id exists, but I need to save the user before checking that.

The code currently looks like this:

```
@user = User.new(params[:user])
@user.roles << Role.new(:name => 'Peon') unless @user.has_roles?
if @user.save
  # ...
```

The only ways I can think of getting around the problem involves either disabling the validation, which I don't want to do, or double-saving to the DB, which isn't exactly efficient.

What's the standard way for handling this issue?

Comment: Couldn't you just do this in two steps, first saving the user and then adding the role and saving it?

Comment: The OP mentioned that and didn't seem to want to do it. "double-saving to the DB, which isn't exactly efficient."

Comment: I see. This may be relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1025292/how-can-you-validate-the-presence-of-a-belongs-to-association-with-rails

Comment: @AndrewHubbs Except there is no "double-saving". Each of these incurs exactly two `INSERT`s.

Comment: Yes I think the double-saving efficiency issue is not really an issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you can get around the validation problem if you change your code to look like this:

```
@user = User.new(params[:user])
@user.roles.new(:name => 'Peon') unless @user.has_roles?
if @user.save
  # ...
```

If that doesn't work, you could try changing you validation to this:

```
class Role < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  validates :user_id, :presence => true, :unless => Proc.new() {|r| r.user}
end
```

Answer (score 10):

After researching a bit, this solution seems to be easiest. First, in your `Role` model, instead of validating `user_id`, validate `user`:

```
validates :user, :presence => true
```

Then, in your `User` model, add `:inverse_of => :user` to your `has_many` call:

```
has_many :roles, :inverse_of => :user
```

Then it works as expected:

```
irb(main):001:0> @user = User.new
=> #<User id: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
irb(main):002:0> @user.roles << Role.new(:name => "blah")
=> [#<Role id: nil, user_id: nil, name: "blah", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>]
irb(main):003:0> @user.roles[0].user
=> #<User id: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
irb(main):004:0> @user.save
  (0.1ms)  begin transaction
 SQL (3.3ms)  INSERT INTO "users" ("created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?)  [["created_at", Fri, 04 Jan 2013 02:29:33 UTC +00:00], ["updated_at", Fri, 04 Jan 2013 02:29:33 UTC +00:00]]
 User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 3 LIMIT 1
 SQL (0.2ms)  INSERT INTO "roles" ("created_at", "name", "updated_at", "user_id") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)  [["created_at", Fri, 04 Jan 2013 02:29:34 UTC +00:00], ["name", "blah"], ["updated_at", Fri, 04 Jan 2013 02:29:34 UTC +00:00], ["user_id", 3]]
  (1.9ms)  commit transaction
=> true
irb(main):005:0> @user.roles.first
=> #<Role id: 4, user_id: 3, name: "blah", created_at: "2013-01-04 02:29:34", updated_at: "2013-01-04 02:29:34">
```

Note, however, that this still produces two SQL transactions, one to save the user and one to save the role. I don't see how you can avoid that.

See also: [How can you validate the presence of a belongs to association with Rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1025292/how-can-you-validate-the-presence-of-a-belongs-to-association-with-rails)

Answer (score 3):

You must take a look at [ActiveRecord's Callbacks](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html). Probably you will use the `before_validation` to do it.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone Googling for a solution to this problem for a `has_many :through` association, as of 5/December/2013 the `:inverse_of` option can't be used in conjunction with `:through` ([source](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_many)).  Instead, you can use the approach suggested by @waldyr.ar.  For example, if our models are set up as follows:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :roles
  has_many :tasks, through: roles
end

class Role < ActiveRecord::Base  
  belongs_to :user  
  belongs_to :task  
end

class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :roles
  has_many :users, through: roles
end
```

We can modify our `Role` class as follows to validate the presence of both `task` and `user` before saving

```
class Role < ActiveRecord::Base  
  belongs_to :user  
  belongs_to :task  
  before_save { validates_presence_of :user, :task }
end
```

Now if we create a new `User` and add a couple `tasks` like so:

```
>> u = User.new  
>> 2.times { u.tasks << Task.new }
```

Running `u.save` will save the `User` and the `Task`, as well as transparently build and save a new `Role` whose foreign keys `user_id` and `task_id` are set appropriately.  Validations will run for all models, and we can go on our merry way!