# nested_attributes save parent first

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

i had 2 models. `User` and `Company`

**Company**

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :users, dependent: :destroy

  validates :name, 
    presence: true,
    uniqueness: true

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :users
end
```

**User**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :company

  validates :name,
    presence: true

  validates :company,
    presence: true

end
```

And i got a Hash:

```
{:name=>"My Company", :users_attributes=>[{:name=>"My User"}]}
```

Now i run the following:

```
params = {:name=>"My Company", :users_attributes=>[{:name=>"My User"}]}
company = Company.new params
company.save
```

The behaviour is what i'm expected. `company` could not saved, because the  `User` is not valid (validation: `validates :company, presence: true`)

for this, i used everytime a concern class which does the following:

- create company
- create users for this company

so my question is:

Is it possible to save first the parent, and when valid save the childrens as an second part, without using a concern class? does exist for this situation a rails way like "accepts_nested_attributes_and_save_first_parent_for"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try following:

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :users, dependent: :destroy, :inverse_of => :company
  ...
end
```

Refer:

1. [How can you validate the presence of a belongs to association with Rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1025292/how-can-you-validate-the-presence-of-a-belongs-to-association-with-rails)
2. [Rails: Validating association after save?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14150027/rails-validating-association-after-save)

Comment: great, thats do the trick. i didn't know that i'm can use `inverse_of` for this. thats awesome

Comment: Not working for us, still the same issue on a Rails 4.x app